# Dynamic Graphs to Pdf

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, graph

I have some graphs on html which takes data from database using php function and javascripts. How can i create daily pdf with graphs on it of current date data without opening webpage and clicking on button?

Answer (score 1):

The key problem is that HTML (graphics or even just text) does not translate directly into PDF. There are some libraries that will do this to a limited degree, but typically without the level of control that most people want in a PDF.

There are two very different ways to go about this, and I have used both at various times:

1 - Create a batch-mode PHP program (or other server-side language of your choice) that creates the graphics entirely server-side (many libraries available for that).

2 - Capture the page as if you were running a browser. I have used PhantomJS http://phantomjs.org/ to do that. The big advantage is that you can make use of all your existing graphics code - even libraries such as d3.

Either way, you will need to take the output and insert into a PDF together with headers, footers, explanatory text, etc. I usually use R&OS http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/ for the PDF part, but there are other libraries that will work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

try dompdf, it might help you. Here is the link

> https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf